# Outputting HTML Form Data into a DIV Tag In a New Window

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

Hi I currently have an internal website I use that has a form on it that the end user fills out and once they click on submit it opens a new page using javascript to output the form data the user then selects the pre-formatted text in order to copy and paste to another place. The website is ran locally from the user's computer so it will not be on a server.

The problem is if they go back to the form and enter new data and click submit again, the popup window with the previous values stays there and the form clears itself of its data or there are a bunch of popup windows and they will get confused which one is for what.

What I am trying to accomplish is when I click on the submit button the form data is outputted to a div tag in a results.html page where I can include a button to close the window. Also there is more than one page with more than one form so a .js file is not an option.

Here is an example of the coding of one of my pages I used generic names for the form element names and labels.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function display() {
  DispWin = window.open('','_blank', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=800,height=400')
  message = "<b>Field 1: </b>" + document.form1.field1.value + "<br>";
  message += "<b>Field 2: </b>" + document.form1.field2.value + "<br>";  
  message += "<b>Field 3: </b>" + document.form1.field3.value + "<br>";
  message += "<b>Field 4: </b>" + document.form1.field4.value + "<br>";
  DispWin.document.write(message);
}
</script>
<style>
    label {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form name="form1" style="width: 60%">
    <h3>Sample</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Field 1: </label><br><input type="text" name="field1"><br> 
            <label>Field 2:</label><br><input type="text" name="field2"><br> 
            <label>Field 3:</label><br><input type="text" name="field3"><br>
            <label>Field 4</label><br><textarea name="field4" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="display();">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="back.png"></a>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Okay so since my original post I have learned some bootstrap and have redone my website this is the updated code, but I am unable to get the values of the form fields to output to the modal please assist.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid-content container-fluid">
<form>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for='fieldname'>Name: </label>
                <input type='text' name='name' class='form-control' id='fieldname'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for='fieldzip'>Zip Code:</label>
                <input type='text' name='zip' class='form-control' id='fieldzip'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">    
                <label for='fieldopsys'>Favorite Color:</label>
                <input type='text' name='favcolor' class='form-control' id='fieldfavcolor'>
            </div>


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-standard" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-standard" id="clear">Clear</button>

</form>
</div>  
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Results</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <strong>Name: </strong> <span class='results' id='name'></span><br>
              <strong>Zip Code: </strong> <span class='results' id='zip'></span><br>
              <strong>Favorite Color: </strong> <span class='results' id='favcolor'></span><br>
          </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js File

```
 $('form').on('submit', function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.form-control').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('field', '');
    $('.results' + id).text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Please assist.

Comment: Curious why you want to have popups (which may be disabled by popup blockers) instead of using modals?

Comment: Not sure what that is

Comment: That actually looks perfect for what I am looking for and I didn't even know it. So how would i output the form data into the modal?

Comment: Modals (aka overlays, lightboxes, etc) are sections of a page that appear when triggered by an event (click, etc) and can be easily escaped from by clicking outside or the close button.
Here are some examples (look for the Demo links):
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Comment: Let me write an actual answer for that :)

Comment: There's some modal stuff for you below! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, to implement a modal, there are a few options:

- You can use a UI framework like Bootstrap, Foundation, etc to render modals for you. This may be the easiest way to get them running.
- There are modal plugins for jQuery and Javascript libraries that implement them. (I don't know any offhand)
- You can implement your own.

My favoured technique is to make a partial for my modal (if you are using a templating engine) and then include it at the bottom of any page that will open it. The modal could be something like this:

http://jsbin.com/cusicu/edit?html,css,js,output

I quickly wrote this using jQuery... feel free to adapt it to fit your needs (if you prefer VanillaJS or whatever, or want other actions to happen on submit, etc). It should be noted that *usually* clicking the overlay behind the modal will also close the modal (watch out - you have to ensure that it only works for the overlay and not the modal itself) and so will hitting escape, but for the sake of timeliness I omitted those.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the details. I will try it.

Comment: Hey I updated my coding and was wondering if you could help me. I implemented some bootstrap and I am unable to get the values to pass please assist.

Comment: Hey, sorry I haven't been on SO in a little while, do you still need help?

Comment: I do this issue i am having now is i need to convert for the script to work but when the button named submit is clicked it cant be a type of submit because it wont work in firefox. I tried but no luck so far.

Comment: What do you need to convert?

Comment: I need to make it to where the modal will display the results in the form when a button is clicked instead of when the form is submitted. Currently if i use this in firefox and click submit it clears the values in the form and the values of the fields do not carry over to the modal. I think this would be resolved by converting the button which is currently type submit to type button i tried doing this but i could get thr jquery to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up what you want it to display like this:

```
let myContent = "data:text/html," + yourHTML
```

If you want an event to trigger a new window with your html, you can have it open like this:

```
element.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let myContent = "data:text/html," + yourHTML
    window.open(myContent);
});
```

Another way to do it is to have a link set up like this

```
<a class="myLink" target="blank" href="">
```

Then in the script, you can listen to the changes on the form or event for a command in your UI.

```
myLink = document.getElementsByClass('myLink')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit',function(){
    // code for building your html from form values 
    // like yourHTML += document.getElementById('stateSelect').value;
    let myContent = "data:text/html," + yourHTML
    myLink.setAttribute('href', myContent);
    return false;
});
```

Sources:

[Setting attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

[Element Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

[Data URI HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I've created it for you, maybe this is what you want.
I just used a jQuery plugin.

Go here for full code / preview: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AchmaDesigner/zu73dtsb/11/).

This is the sample code HTML:

```
<div>
  <form name="form1" style="width: 60%">
    <h3>Sample</h3>
    <fieldset>
      <label>Field 1: </label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="f1" name="field1">
      <br>
      <label>Field 2:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="f2" name="field2">
      <br>
      <label>Field 3:</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="f3" name="field3">
      <br>
      <label>Field 4</label>
      <br>
      <textarea id="f4" name="field4" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sendData">
      <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="back.png"></a>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the sample code JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).on('click', '#sendData', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var f1 = $('#f1').val(),
            f2 = $('#f2').val(),
            f3 = $('#f3').val(),
            f4 = $('#f4').val();
        var getSendData = '<div>' +
            '<p> Field 1 = ' + f1 + '</p>' +
            '<p> Field 2 = ' + f2 + '</p>' +
            '<p> Field 3 = ' + f3 + '</p>' +
            '<p> Field 4 = ' + f4 + '</p>' + '</div>';
        var contentData = "data:text/html," + getSendData;
        window.open(contentData, "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=400,height=400");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks i will try to do this and see if it helps.